# How do I punctuate a question with a guessed answer in it?

Tags: punctuation, questions

How to punctuate a question directly followed by the asker's guess at the answer? E.g.

> 1. What's in here? Your books?
> 2. What's in here, your books?
> 3. What's in here; your books?

Which of these (if any) is correct?

Comment: What sounds correct to you? The first one?

Comment: I favor #1, particularly when you want to emphasize your curiosity about the contents (such as when someone hands you a surprisingly heavy bag; rendering the first clause as a question underscores your astonishment). I also find #2 perfectly suitable (though it's less emphatic about your curiosity, as I said). I don't like #3 much, it somehow diminishes the interrogative nature, particularly of the first clause.

Comment: *What is/are in here, your books?* works fine. So does #1.

Comment: The English orthography is defective because it has only one question mark for all the different types of questions, which can have very many different intonation patterns. Numbers 2 and 3 seem natural because the first question really has a falling intonation (which we tend to assert with declarative clauses), but number 1 also seems natural because the first question is in fact a question. There is no correct answer, we should just stop writing down things in English.

Answer (score 2):

I would use *What's in here? Your books?* when you're asking a sincere question and then sincerely guessing at the answer.

*What's in here, bricks?* might be used if you're being sarcastic about a possible answer.

And I would never use a semicolon in that example.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with a question mark (1), a comma (2), or an em dash (not a hyphen). A semicolon (3) is not an option.

Comment: I agree with your answer (just made a comment along similar lines), but I can't upvote until you add support (ideally from an external authority).

Comment: I never checked a single authority. I merely read a couple thousand books. Suggesting the OP do likewise is all I have on offer.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, which is why the best I could do for OP was add a comment along those lines.

Comment: Yes; the semicolon doesn't chime. But since the semicolon is usually used to separate independent clauses, and sentence fragments are often treated as such punctuation-wise ... But I'd go with (2) for the usual smooth development, (1) for an afterthought.

Comment: Not sure I’d go as far as to say that a semicolon is _not an option_, but it’s definitely the option I’d be least likely to use. If you answer the question in the title narrowly, though, I’d have to say that #2 (and, at a stretch, #3) is the **only** possible option. #1 makes it two separate questions, unlike #2 which makes the question and the guess one coherent ‘unit’.